# Converting md to docx with pandoc

Tags: vim, markdown, docx, pandoc, odt

I am attempting to use a docx template to convert from markdown to word for pandoc. I am working in [Vim](https://www.vim.org/) with the plugin [Vim-Pandoc](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc) Everything is working fine except that the header, including name and such is not printing. Here is what my markdown document looks like. At the top is the yaml data.

```
---
title: "blah"
author: "blah"
---

# section

The body often looks like this...

# Works Cited
```

However, I've also tried without the yaml data at the top, instead marking the title like this

```
%Title
```

The title is still populated but none of the template data is brought over.

My command looks like

```
Pandoc docx --filter=pandoc-citeproc --bibliography=~/VimWiki/blah.bib --reference-doc=/PATH/TO/reference.docx
```

The title and bib stuff print just fine. However the template that I am using using print a mla style template as a header but none of the header information is printing. How do I get headers print?

Comment: why do you have yaml data if you're trying to convert from markdown to .docx?

Comment: That's a really good question and one I am not sure how to answer. The only good it seems to do is provide author and title information but nothing else.

Comment: From the way I understand it, I should be able to customize the yaml data at the top of my document which should then update the actual docx file. It does but only the name field and title.